# Parse Dashboard bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, parse-dashboard

When I try to go to Parse Dashboard on ***https://www.example.net/dashboard*** it's redirecting me to ***https://www.example.net/login***. and here I'm getting this error. GET ***https://example.net/bundles/login.bundle.js*** net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) Also the result is blank. just a white screen.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Parse server have problem not in dashboard parse server cannot read your database Uri or username password you want to change all you want to change server url or master key or appId in https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example/blob/master/index.js or your index.js file

[change here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zrm6.png)